# Need help getting data using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to get Python and selenium to store the "1292" in the following html script and cant figure out why it won't work. I've tried using find_element_by_xpath as well as placing a wait before it and I keep getting this error "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Any ideas on how else I can accomplish this? Thanks

`<text x="76.76666666666667" y="141.42345774407445" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#4572A7;font-size:11px;fill:#4572A7;" text-anchor="middle" zIndex="1">
     <tspan x="76.76666666666667">1292</tspan>
   </text>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tspan[text()='1292']").text`
to obtain the string "1292".